# Can I hook error_log(...)?

Tags: logging

Is there a hook for error_log(...) ?
On my development environment I would like to var_dump the results instead of having to check the log file each time.

Comment: error_log() is a PHP function not a WordPress one so there are no hooks for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using standard function from PHP [set_error_handler()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php)